# Can't read this code from Apple template

Tags: objective-c, datasource

I do not understand the Objective-C in the following method taken from Apple's Master Detail Template:

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    if (!_objects)
    {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0
                                                inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: @[indexPath]
                          withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

The code is in the MasterViewController.m file.    The points of confusion for me are:
  - what does `@[indexPath]` mean?  Is this a syntax for making something an array.  I have only run into the '@' as the character denoting a string. Clarification: I understand what an NSIndexPath is and how it functions.  I am not familiar with the syntax for putting an object in brackets preceded by the @ character.  Does this make something an array?  What if I had several NSIndexPaths?  Can I load all of them into an array in this manner  @[indexPath1, indexPath2, indexPath3]  Does this work with anything derived from NSObject?  Is the result always an array?  Where is this documented in the language - what is this language feature called (so I can look it up)?

- The method insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation seems to specify the locations to put something into the table but not exactly what to put.  How does the method know what object to use as the data source when inserting items into the table.  The delegate and data source relationships are specified in the xib so it is apparent that the MasterViewController will handle the association of data with the table, but there does not seem to be any relationship with the `NSMutable *_objects;` array and the table specified anywhere.

Thanks for the help in explaining this as it is apparent I am missing some pretty basic stuff.

Comment: *"I do not understand the C++"* - do you mean Objective C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a syntax for making something an array

Yes. In modern Objective-C, as understood by the latest `clang` compiler, there are some more `@` directives for easily creating hard-coded objects:

```
@[object1, object2]
```

creates an NSArray;

```
@{@"key1": value1, @"key2": value2}
```

creates an NSDictionary,

```
@"hello world"
```

creates an NSString, as usually, and

```
@1, @2, @YES, @3.1415927
```

create NSNumber instances, respectively.

> How does the method know what object to use as the data source when inserting items into the table.

It uses the data source currently set on the table view it is called on.

Comment: thanks for the explanation of the language feature.  What is the name of this feature so that I can read up on it?  I am still confused on the data source issue.  If I added another NSMutable array to the MasterViewController object which array would it use when taking data and putting it in the table?  As I understand it the datasource only applies to the MasterViewController class not specifically to the ivars in the class.  How is it that I am specifying the array to use as the data source in the code.  I don't see it in the call to insertRows. Thanks, I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: @StoneBreaker they're called, logically, "object literals". If you add another array, that still doesn't matter. The table view will always use the one that is set as its data source.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess that is my trouble.  I don't see anywhere in the xib or the code that I am setting the NSMutableArray *_objects as the datasource.  In the connections inspector I find the File's Owner - in this case MasterViewController as the dataSource and the delegate.  There is no reference to dataSource or delegate in the source at all.  How does the compiler and run time know to use that iVar _objects in the MasterViewController?

Comment: OK, I get it.  What is happening is that the dataSource protocol is invoked with each of the indexPath's in the array.  The association of the array with the table is made in the methods of the dataSource protocol.  Best link I found for 'object literals' (Thanks @H2CO3) is http://blog.bignerdranch.com/398-objective-c-literals-part-1/

Comment: @StoneBreaker The compiler doesn't know that by itself. Probably you couldn't yet find the reference, but it's sure that somewhere in the code, somehow, the data source of the table view is set explicitly to an object which in turn uses the array.